# How to get time between inputs in list c#?

Tags: c#, time

So I have a program that gets values when I press buttons on a remote control. Those values are saved in a list as I press the buttons. I use TimerCOM_Tick to keep the reading updated. Now I need to get the time between one button and the next.

How can I do that?

Comment: Save the DateTime.Now whenever you click a button, and subtrack the oldest from the newest to get a TimeSpan with the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your timestamps are instances of [`System.DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) you can substract them to get difference, which is a [`System.TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var t1 = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
var t2 = DateTime.Now;
var difference = (t1 - t2);
Console.WriteLine(difference.TotalSeconds);
```

If your timestamps are not instances of `DateTime` than you need to convert them to `DateTime` first.